# Separar elementos de una sublista

Tags: python, diccionarios

tengo una duda acerca de como poder separar elementos dentro de una sublista, cada termino. Por ejemplo dentro de mi lista uno de sus elementos es:

A-82899,TECNICAS DE INVESTIGACION Y DOCUMENTACION,SOLORZANO DE NAN NAYETH.,ESPOL,IBM4381,2003,8/22/2013,8,FCNM

eso es mi elemento con indice 0 en mi lista, lo que quiero es poder separar ese elemento por comas, es decir: ''A-82899','TECNICAS DE INVESTIGACION.'...' y asi.

Comment: Sebastian esa estructura aparentemente es un csv. ¿Obtienes tu lista de un fichero csv? Lo digo porque en tal caso sería mucho más simple usar el módulo csv de la biblioteca estándar. En caso contrario la solución es `str.split` como MigHc afirma en su respuesta, algo como `lista_split = [cad.split(",") for cad in lista]`.

Answer (score 0):

def hh():

```
a=['A-82899,TECNICAS DE INVESTIGACION Y DOCUMENTACION,SOLORZANO DE NAN NAYETH.,ESPOL,IBM4381,2003,8/22/2013,8,FCNM']

qq=[]
for i in a[0]:
    if i==',':
        m+=1
    elif i!=',':
        h=e[m]+i
        e.append(h)
w=[]
for i in a[0]:
    w.append(i)
x=(' ')
for i in w:
    if i!=',':
        z=i
        x=x+z
    elif i==',':
        qq.append(x)
        x=(' ')
print(qq)
```

hh()